# How is this optoisolator being sensed by an input?

Tags: opto-isolator, input

I'm trying to replace a mains input opto-isolator (pictured below) which is connected to an input on an industrial control board.

I would have though shorting the input would be enough but this is not the case. There is an input LED on the board which changes state however it doesn't activate the desired function in the controller

I don't have access to remove the board so I can't see what kind of input circuit it is - but from the above testing I'm assuming it's an ADC.

The large SMD device on the input can't be a PTC as i've drawn here - I think it would have to be a diode for reverse polarity protection.

The resistor above it is 47R - I'm assuming that this is all that is required to trigger the input. I'm going to purchase a few resistor values to test (i've tested tested down to about 500R with the resistors I have on hand and it hasn't worked)

Is there anything else I'm missing?

[image: ANAE-V2]

Comment: I'm assuming I should be able to fully mimic the output side of the isolator with a diode, resistor and cap, i'm doubtful that the input is sensing the non-linearity of the diode, the time-constant of the capacitor - its most likely just the resistor to set the right ADC value?

Comment: There is a schematic editor on this site.  Please edit your question and add a schematic, with part numbers if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit uses a power resistor to drop up 360Vpk or 5mA into Full Wave Diode Bridge then LED. The output current thus saturates the effective Darlington inverter so that only zero crossings are pull-up except when the input current drops below the threshold which may be in the 1mA range.  Thus it is possible to generate a 1% zero-crossing positive pulse at 2x grid frequencies.

[simple simulation.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzBMI6QBxgMwEYBscAsyBOXAVjiw1xFzRAwlzgCgAXENMSvCNNLRXCBAwgAtGGhoA7JIIE4GNMQJYwWAqWJQsPbFmTI4k-WCMFaMRgHc2vRGGQ2%20cPOCtsOdhzyf3X174jEfAHslGCMAE7unALRcUKwFlEBcL4BFGHmFgAmtLickggZ-BAI2QCmAGYAhgCuADbMbun5VDB5Yc22qQ4Cpb7hAEqOHSPK4BOxmoJQxIy5xT2jGJJOIBU1DU3WxSt8e7SrrlHYtHIg4xjnEEGwjADmcaFPtoKMAPJt-b34nhPhCyOzkoBwOZSqdUa80OTkKMMQLnBmyhO1aXFGS3COyBLnG6KxGLhYLh4QEkj%20S3RSwwblBQN8BwJlNilJJblZRSBbP8tmefI84QAxl9Rn0-qVIKlEtLEnByiI6FRIGg4AR0Gg1bwMMRkMRhOIYDSAG60JyxU5XBBCEDEbi2-6zNx481mt7WS7nRYDRhSb7wykM-6MAQ0fBCDAIPQORmIAgAfSwuDjYDjEeIxDQyeghqzMBwqSCGCu2rDyAwybjcEr8czAEkADoAZwAMgBRAAiwfQVFQfyjiH0EyriYr2AMYCrqVzMA1qjgxArk7jmYAak2APa1JohkpsVJsPRsZCZJMjlMR1Up8RYUiyZBofTEQqq3Dlg05lNVpNoRjrvIgBx6FtHVzGzLBpETQguEkCMoFgfVaEYIA)
[image]

I omitted the MOV on the output stage.

Comment: I think you are correct here - Why do I always thing about things as DC. It's possible that it is detecting the 100hz pulse (2x 50hz). I'll put a frequency DMM on it to see if the pulse is visible or if it is smoothed by the capacitor.

Comment: The pulse is not detectable by a DMM - it's likely smoothed completely - and thinking about it again the SMD across the output is likely a large capacitor for this purpose.

Comment: Show all the transistor voltage to find your problem. Vbe , Vce etc if 1% of 5V, the DMM might show a low Vac

Comment: I've found a scope and I can confirm that the pulse on ZVC is clearly visible. I'll replicate a 100hz pulse train to confirm.